# Outlook Error MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED at Save() RDOEmail

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

Calling Save() twice raice MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED error. The weird thing is if I select another mail on the grid and go back and then select the first one again and perform the action it works fine. This only happens with imap accounts. 
Code:

```
public void UpdateMailObject(bool linked)
{
    Outlook._Application outlookApplication = null;
    Redemption.RDOMail rdoEmail = null;
    Redemption.RDOSession rdoSession = null;
    RDOFolder folder = null;
    RDOStores stores = null;
    RDOStore store = null;
    RDOStore unwStore = null;
    Outlook.Explorer outlookExplorer = null;
    Outlook.MailItem selectedMail = null;
    try
    {
        outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
        rdoSession = new Redemption.RDOSession();
        object MAPIOBJECT = outlookApplication.Session.GetType().InvokeMember("MAPIOBJECT", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                outlookApplication.Session, null);
        rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = MAPIOBJECT;
        outlookExplorer = outlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
        selectedMail = outlookExplorer.Selection.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>().FirstOrDefault();

        RDOMail rdoMailAux = rdoSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(selectedMail, true) as RDOMail;
        folder = rdoMailAux.Parent as RDOFolder;
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdoMailAux);
        string storeId = folder.StoreID;
        stores = rdoSession.Stores;
        store = stores.GetStoreFromID(storeId);
        unwStore = stores.UnwrapStore(store);
        rdoEmail = unwStore.GetMessageFromID(selectedMail.EntryID, null);

        string sGUID = PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS.ToString("B");
        int iID = rdoEmail.GetIDsFromNames(sGUID, GMLINK);

        if (iID != 0)
        {
            rdoEmail.set_Fields(iID, linked);
        }

        rdoEmail.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (outlookApplication != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookApplication);
        }
        if (folder != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
        }
        if (stores != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(stores);
        }
        if (store != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
        }
        if (unwStore != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(unwStore);
        }
        if (rdoEmail != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdoEmail);
        }
        if (outlookExplorer != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookExplorer);
        }

        if (rdoSession != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rdoSession);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: @codenamezero you had a similar problem right?

Comment: Do yo use the same problem if you use GetMessageFromId instead of GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject?

Comment: Yes. If I call GetMessageFromId() from rdoSession I get the same error.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I'm using Outlook 2016 btw

Comment: was this ever resolved? i am having the same issue and have been stuck for days

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko any solution for this? I am having the exact problem and have also tried GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject

Comment: @user3771957 - you can work around this problem under Exchange by calling SaveAs without a file name ("") passing flags instead of the type - Redemption would know it will need to call IMessage::SaveChange instead of creating a file. Pass FORCE_SAVE (=4) - that will overwrite the message even if there is a conflict. But I don't think that flag works under the IMAP4 store.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work for me either because, as you mentioned, this is an IMAP account.